# Django Admin: want to prepopulate some fields when I click the add button (+) next to a foreign key

Tags: django-admin

In the Django Admin I want to use data from the current record to populate fields for a foreign key record when I click the add (+) button next to the drop-down list.

For example, I am viewing an instance of `X` which has fields for `a`, `b`, and `c` and a foreign key `Y`.
`Y` also has fields for `a`, `b`, and `c`, so when I click on the "add" button on the `X` instance, I want the `a`, `b`, and `c` fields for the new `Y` instance to be populated with the values from the `X` instance.

Obviously these fields would not be pre-populated if I just go to "add new Y" in the admin!

I have searched quite a bit to no avail!

Anyone had any success?

(I'm using django 1.3 with Python 2.6; I don't think any code snippets are required here.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, may be a bit too late but I think this is the answer

Django support url param in admin. You can do like this

```
http://localhost/admin/app/model/add/?model_field=value
```

then you can add foreign key by replace model_field with your foreign key name and value with the ID. Hope this help someone else :D

Comment: You mean: `{% url admin:app_model_add %}?model_field={{myobject.id}}` ;) Indeed, useful if you control the place where this link gets created.

Answer (score 0):

So you would prefer to have an additional button called "Add new Y" that inserts another row into Y with data from X?

Then override the save() method on X so it inserts a row into Y every time it gets called.