# Django admin: Prefill data when clicking the add-another button next to a ForeignKey dropdown

Tags: django, django-admin

In the Django Admin, when you modify an objects properties, if there is a ForeignKey, it will have a dropdown box of all the choices, plus a "+" button to add more choices. When I click on it, I want to prefill some of the data.

I've noticed I could do it if I could modify the URL (example: `http://localhost:8000/admin/app/model/add/?field=value` where `field` and `value` are programmatically modified.)

I figure I have to override something in the `forms.ModelForm` that the `admin.ModelAdmin` uses, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Could you post the source code of the model which has the fields you want to prefill?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9935176, https://stackoverflow.com/q/23559771, https://stackoverflow.com/q/10219494

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django allows you to replace a request's GET dict (which it uses to pre-populate the admin form).

Django will automatically fill values from URL GET parameters if you are sending field values of model form in the URL.

For example, considering
`"http://myhost/admin/app/model/add/?name=testname"`, it will prefill the `name` field of the form in the admin add-view template with the value `'testname'`.

But, if you are sending any id in your URL, you need to modify the GET parameters by overriding the `add_view` function.

Taken from stackoverflow answer

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...

    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        source_id = request.GET.get('source',None)
        if source_id != None:
            source = FeedPost.objects.get(id=source_id)
            # any extra processing can go here...
            g = request.GET.copy()
            g.update({
                'title':source.title,
                'contents':source.description + u"... \n\n[" + source.url + "]",
            })

            request.GET = g

        return super(ArticleAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)
```

It just an example.DO it with Your model and fields :)

Comment: I don't see `source_id` in `request.GET`. Using Django 3.1.1

Comment: @AfsanAbdulaliGujarati,   source or source_id is something you can send from another link/button

Answer (score 3):

This is old, but it can be quite a puzzle, and the accepted answer did not address the true issue for me.

The question, as I understand it, is how to pre-fill data on the related model's admin form, which pops up after you click the green `+` ("Add another") next to a widget for a `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField`. This is illustrated below.

[image: image showing admin form with add-another and related pop-up form]

As suggested in the [(currently) accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21276526), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19205297), this can be achieved by adding URL parameters for each of the fields that you want to pre-fill. This is also illustrated in the image.

The question that remains unanswered, however, is:

How, exactly, can we add these URL parameters to the URL used by the `+` ("Add another") link?

*Assuming the pre-filled values depend on a the current state of the form on the client side*, e.g. the selected `organization` in the image above, I suppose it makes sense to use JavaScript.

Note: If the pre-filled values do not depend on the form state, nor on the current request, [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10001513) might be more appropriate.

Here's a minimal example that was used to create the image above:

**models.py**: (we put the admin stuff in here as well for convenience)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin


class Organization(models.Model):
    pass


class Participant(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(to=Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Event(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(to=Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(to=Participant)


admin.site.register(Organization)
admin.site.register(Participant)
admin.site.register(Event)
```

Now we extend the Django admin `change_form` template (based on the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/javascript)) for our `Event` model with a little bit of JavaScript.

Follow [these](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#set-up-your-projects-admin-template-directories) instructions to set-up your templates folder, and don't forget to add you templates folder to `DIRS` in `settings.TEMPLATES`.

**templates/admin/my_app/event/change_form.html**:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}
{{ block.super }}

<script type="text/javascript">
var add_participant_url = document.getElementById("add_id_participants").href;
var organization = document.getElementById("id_organization")
organization.onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("add_id_participants").href =
        add_participant_url + "&organization=" + organization.value;
};
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

DISCLAIMER: I have limited experience with JavaScript, so any suggestions for improvement are welcome.

Basically, whenever the user changes the selected organization on the "Change event" form, the URL for the "Add another participant" (+) link is updated with the selected value, so the organization field on the "Add participant" form will be pre-filled.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative to my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563187).

This alternative does not use JavaScript, so it works server-side only, which has a number of drawbacks. Nevertheless, some parts of the puzzle may be of use to someone.

The basic idea is this:

The "Add another" (+) button provides a link to the related model admin view.

The URL for this link is constructed in the [related_widget_wrapper.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/widgets/related_widget_wrapper.html#L16) template.

This template uses a `url_params` variable, which is created in the [RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper.get_context()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L283) method.

To pre-fill the related form, we need to append our custom URL parameters to this `url_params` variable, in the context of the widget, so we can utilize the default widget template.

The simplest way to achieve this, as far as I can see, is to create a wrapper for the `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper.get_context()` method.

We then extend the `ModelAdmin.formfield_for_dbfield()` method, and use our custom wrapper there, so it has access to the current request.

As far as I know, the `formfield_for_dbfield` method is not mentioned in the [ModelAdmin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options)...), but this is [where Django applies the RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L172).

NOTE: If you are trying to do [something similar for a raw-id-field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23617858), there is an easier way, viz. by extending `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget.url_parameters()` ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.1/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L167)).

Here's a minimal example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin


class Organization(models.Model):
    pass


class Participant(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(to=Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Event(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(to=Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(to=Participant)


def wrap_extra_url_params(original_get_context, extra_url_params: str):
    def get_context_with_extra_url_params(*args, **kwargs):
        context = original_get_context(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'url_params' in context:
            context['url_params'] += '&{}'.format(extra_url_params)
        return context
    return get_context_with_extra_url_params


class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        formfield = super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'participants':
            # get event organization from current request
            event_id = request.resolver_match.kwargs.get('object_id', None)
            if event_id:
                event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
                # override the "add another participant" link
                formfield.widget.get_context = wrap_extra_url_params(
                    original_get_context=formfield.widget.get_context,
                    extra_url_params='organization={}'.format(
                        event.organization_id))
        return formfield


admin.site.register(Organization)
admin.site.register(Participant)
admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)
```

Note that the server-side has no way of knowing whether the user changes the selected organization, so it only works when modifying existing `Event` instances.

This works, to a certain degree, but I would go for the JavaScript option.

Answer (score 1):

Aks's answer didn't work for me as I couldn't find the `source` field in `request.GET` dict. However, I was able to make it work by adding the following function to my `TestAdmin` class - This is the admin that opens up on clicking the add button

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(TestAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    // using URL pattern to get the refrrer object id 
    admin_referer = re.match(".*(/adminame/)(.+)(/change/)", 
                                        request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

    if request.GET.get('_popup', None) and admin_referer:
        test_model = TestModel.objects.get(id=admin_referer[2])
        form.base_fields['prepopulate_field'].initial = test_model
        form.base_fields['prepopulate_field'].widget.can_add_related = False
        form.base_fields['prepopulate_field'].widget.can_change_related = False
        form.base_fields['prepopulate_field'].widget.can_delete_related = False
        
    return form
```

I would have preferred a better way to fetch the referer's object id, but I could only make this way to work.